# Creating violin plots on ggplot2 for vectors of different length?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I have two vectors of different length, and want to create a violin plots for them. What I am currently doing is to `cbind` them, which makes the shorter vector to be repeated until it matches the length of the longer vector (by default done by `cbind` in R).

```
library(ggplot2)

C1 <- rnorm(100)
C2 <- rnorm(500)

dat <- cbind(C1,C2)

# Violin plots for columns
mat <- reshape2::melt(data.frame(dat), id.vars = NULL)
pp <- ggplot(mat, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_violin(scale="width",adjust = 1,width = 0.5,fill = "gray80")
pp
```

Would this affect the shape of the violin?  Is there a more correct way of creating the violin plots without having to artificially increase the length of one of them?

Comment: `ggplot` expects long-shaped data, so you shouldn't be `cbind`ing these as two separate columns. Repeating values in one means values appear more often than they should, which would change the shape. Instead, make 2 data frames, with some sort of ID column to show whether it's C1 or C2, and `rbind` them into long data. Skip the `melt` and see what happens when you plot

Comment: You're `cbind`ing into wide format and then using `melt` to get to a long format. Go straight to a long format with `dat = data.frame(value = c(C1, C2), variable = c(rep("C1", length(C1)), rep("C2", length(C2))))`.

Comment: @camille and Gregor Sound like reasonable suggestions. I could accept them as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `cbind`ing two vectors with different lengths, which will cause recycling, and then melting, make two data frames where you mark what each represents and `rbind` them. That way you start out with data in the shape that `ggplot` expects, and don't run the risk of repeating values from the shorter of the two sets of data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(710)
C1 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(100), variable = "C1")
C2 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(500), variable = "C2")

dat <- rbind(C1, C2)
head(dat)
#>         value variable
#> 1 -0.97642446       C1
#> 2 -0.51938107       C1
#> 3  1.05793223       C1
#> 4 -0.88139935       C1
#> 5 -0.05997154       C1
#> 6  0.31960235       C1

ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "width", adjust = 1, width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: If you're creating a plot with two vectors lengths should the size of C1 (n=100) not be thinner (few values) than C2 (n=500).

Comment: @Cyrille not sure what you're asking exactly but a violin plot is a smoothed density of each distribution. By default, the width isn't determined by *counts* but by *density*; you can change that based on computed variables

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the relative distributions and not the magnitude then **@camille's answer is ideal**.

Consider however that you may wish, or it may be more appropriate, to show the **relative sizes** of the two vector lengths in the violin plot.

There are other ways but the best that I found is [ggbeeswarm](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm).

Prep data using camille's code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(710)
C1 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(100), variable = "C1")
C2 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(500), variable = "C2")

dat <- rbind(C1, C2)
```

### Example 1

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=value, y=variable, col=as.factor(variable))) +
  geom_quasirandom(groupOnX = FALSE, varwidth = TRUE)
```

[image: geom_quasirandom]

### Example 2

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=value, y=variable, col=as.factor(variable))) +
  geom_beeswarm(groupOnX = FALSE)
```

[image: geom_beeswarm]

There's lots of other options - see the [documentation](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm).

Are these still violin plots? Perhaps not, but they represent the data more clearly to the viewer.